# Extracting information and adding more details to an imported image of a plot

Tags: plotting, image-processing, ocr

I have the following image that has been created using another program.

[image: image from another program]

Is there a way for Mathematica to load this image, "understand" the limits of the frame (horizontal axis between -1 and +1 and the vertical axis between -0.6 and +0.6), and add more options, such as points, labels, arrows, etc?

Comment: You can upload the image via Import then use ImageCompose to insert graphic items into the plot.  Not sure about extracting the plot limits from a jpg file though.

Answer (score 4):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Cqb.jpg"];

bottom = ColorNegate @ ImagePad[ImageTrim[ColorNegate @ img, 
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {ImageDimensions[img][[1]], 200}]], 10];

StringSplit[TextRecognize[bottom], "\n" ..]
```

> ```
> {"-1.0", "-0.8", "-0.6", "-0.4", "-0.2", "0.0", "0.2", "0.4", "0.6", "0.8", "1.0"}
> ```

Somehow, the axis label is missed. We get the label with additional trimming and adding the option `RecognitionPrior -> "Word"` (or `RecognitionPrior -> "Character"`) :

```
TextRecognize[ImageTrim[bottom, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {ImageDimensions[img][[1]], 100}]], 
 RecognitionPrior -> "Word"]
```

> ```
> "Y"
> ```

The same method for the left frame has two issues: (1) minus sign (`-`)  is *recognized* as underscore (`_`) , and (2) the axis label with diacritics (`OverDot[y]`) is recognized as `"y o-o"`. Both issues can be fixed with a simple `StringReplace`:

```
left = ColorNegate @ ImagePad[ImageTrim[ColorNegate @ img, 
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {200, ImageDimensions[img][[2]]}]], 10];

StringReplace[{"_"->"-", a_~~" o_o" :> ToString[OverDot[a], StandardForm]}] @ 
  StringSplit[TextRecognize[left], "\n"..]
```

> ```
>  {0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,Overscript[y, .],-0.1,-0.2,-0.3,-0.4,-0.5,-0.6}
> ```